# mod_rewrite... renaming urls and getting them to work properly

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is the url that I have that works:

> example.com/php/statePage.php?region_slug=new-york-colleges

Here is what I am trying to get the url to appear as:

> example.com/new-york-colleges.html

I have tried several things so far and I think I am getting close but this is my first PHP / MySQL site and first time using .htaccess.

Here is my .htaccess so far:

> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteRule ^/([^/.]+).html?$ php/statePage.php?region_slug=$1 [L]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  If you could explain what I was missing or what I did wrong, that would help me more... I am trying to learn how to do this and simply giving me the cut and paste method will only help me today.

THANK YOU, this means a lot to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)\.html/?$ php/statePage.php?region_slug=$1 [L]
```

Two things to point out:

When `.` is used in rewrite syntax, it represents *any* character.  So your current rule says **replace anything that's NOT any character, followed by '.html'**.  To work around this, escape your dot like so `\.`.  There are several special characters in rewrite syntax such as this.  It would benefit you to pay attention to them.

Second, I'm not sure if this is *rewrite canon* or not, but I've never personally used forward slashes at the start of a rewrite rule before, and that may or may not impact the rule itself.  Any user with a clarification on this is encouraged to reply.

**EDIT:**  The following characters are marked as special characters in rewrite syntax (and all regular expressions, for that matter), and as such, need to be escaped with a backslash `\` in order to be used literally - `[\^$.|?*+()`

Also, you may find [this reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) useful in further understanding the correct syntax for regular expressions.

Comment: Thank you... my urls are now working.  I'm not exactly sure what a rewrite canon is but the reason the / was at the beginning was because I was trying lots of things to see if it worked before I asked for help (trial and error method).  Thanks for the clarification.  I am beginning to be familiar with regular expressions and I use this a lot: http://regexpal.com/